# Fatal Exception but no crash (Android)

Tags: android, exception

I am getting a lot of the following:

```
/AndroidRuntime(25329): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-1276

E/AndroidRuntime(25329): java.lang.NullPointerException
```

But at every place where i get this exception, I do have a proper check for null. 
Also, I get these exceptions but there is no crash. 
So, what do the exceptions mean, if there is no crash and the app is running smoothly.

code:

```
if (jObject != null){
jObject.removelisteners();
jObject = null;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: post your code. maybe you catch it... and print it.

Comment: but if i have a check for null then why the exception

Comment: why don't post the code? also... the stacktrace should point to a line in your code.. post that code.

Comment: sorry, i just posted the line in the code to which the stack trace points. pls let me know if you need anything else also.

Comment: I think you have the line numbers wrong.  In my opinion, it is not possible for the code you've shown to throw a NullPointerException.  Please post the full stack trace.

Comment: One quick question, there are lots of comments in my code. it is that the line number in the compiled code removes the comments and hence i see different line numbers

Comment: ok my bad, actually what i was seeing was the logcat for the older version of my code. Since i did not do "adb logcat -c" even the earlier exceptions were shown and I was confused about the line numbers. Thanks to all